# Can Facebook Messenger Webview access the LocalStorage API to store data on client side?

Tags: facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I want to store 6 booleans on the user side, if he reaches 6 sites in a city.
Can I use LocalStorage or even cookies, inside the Messenger Webview ?

If I close the Webview and open it again, will the data be still there ?

Answer (score 0):

After test, yes it can. 
So you can easily open a button to the Webview like that in your botfile app.js on the server :

```
function openWebview(sender_psid, text,button_text){
    let button_response = {
    "attachment": {
      "type": "template",
      "payload": {
        "template_type": "button",
        "text": text,
        "buttons": [
          {
            "type":"web_url",
            "url":"<URL>",
            "title":button_text,
            "webview_height_ratio": "compact",
            "messenger_extensions": "true",
            "fallback_url": "<FB_URL>"
          }
        ],
      }
    }
  }
  callSendAPI(sender_psid, button_response);
}
```

to be complete...

```
function callSendAPI(sender_psid, response) {
  // Construct the message body
   let request_body = {
     "recipient": {
       "id": sender_psid
     },
     "message": response
   }
  request({
    "uri": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages",
    "qs": { "access_token": PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN },
    "method": "POST",
    "json": request_body
  }, (err, res, body) => {
    if (!err) {
      console.log('message sent!')
    } else {
      console.error("Unable to send message:" + err);
    }
  });
}
```

and on index.html on client side by example you can store simple data as easy as :

```
<div id='myDiv'>nothing for the moment</div>
<script>
    localStorage.setItem('key1','myValue1')
    var test = localStorage.getItem('key1')
    document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML = test
</script>
```

You will now see 'myValue1' displayed on  the Facebook Messenger Webview